# Variable is undefined error. Calling a variable outside of condition in python

Tags: python

I'm parsing xml data and when i print the variable inside the condition but when i call that same variable later is not defined. Why does this happen

Here the variable "LaunchPath works fine:

```
import xml.sax

class PathHandler( xml.sax.ContentHandler ):
   def __init__(self):
      self.CurrentData = ""

   # Call when an element starts
   def startElement(self, tag, attributes):
      self.CurrentData = tag
      if tag == "application":
         LaunchApp = attributes["android:name"].replace(".", "/")
         LaunchPath = LaunchApp + ".smali"
         print LaunchPath

if ( __name__ == "__main__"):

   # create an XMLReader
   parser = xml.sax.make_parser()
   # turn off namepsaces
   parser.setFeature(xml.sax.handler.feature_namespaces, 0)

   # override the default ContextHandler
   Handler = PathHandler()
   parser.setContentHandler( Handler )

   parser.parse("AndroidManifest.xml")
```

But when i attempt to print "LaunchPath" at the bottom like this it doesn work:

```
import xml.sax

class PathHandler( xml.sax.ContentHandler ):
   def __init__(self):
      self.CurrentData = ""

   # Call when an element starts
   def startElement(self, tag, attributes):
      self.CurrentData = tag
      if tag == "application":
         LaunchApp = attributes["android:name"].replace(".", "/")
         LaunchPath = LaunchApp + ".smali"

if ( __name__ == "__main__"):

   # create an XMLReader
   parser = xml.sax.make_parser()
   # turn off namepsaces
   parser.setFeature(xml.sax.handler.feature_namespaces, 0)

   # override the default ContextHandler
   Handler = PathHandler()
   parser.setContentHandler( Handler )

   parser.parse("AndroidManifest.xml")

print LaunchPath
```

This gives me an error that "LaunchPath" is undefined.

Why does this happen and how can i fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your variable LaunchPath is defined inside the scope of the function `startElement`, since you declared it there when the functions returns it also "erases" the variable.

You should read about [python scopes](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/scope-of-variables-python)

Comment: Thank you. I added global LaunchPath before defining it.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `LaunchPath` is a local variable and you are trying to reference it out of its scope.